# mongoid_fulltext - AND in a query

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I do a `AND` in a query with mongoid_fulltext?

Example:

```
Post.fulltext_search 'rails AND mongo'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using mongoid_fulltext...